# Nested Transparent View with background color in react native?

Tags: css, react-native, styled-components

i want to add a transparent child view with background color, so what i did is the child has border bottom left radius and it's transparent and it's parent has background color of white but this is what i achieved, what i want to do is the white background not override the transparent view with border bottom left radius:

[image: result]

my current code:

```
<StyledView1>
  <StyledView2 />
</StyledView1>
<MainContentContainer
  topRightRadius
  bottomLeftRadius
  bottomRightRadius
> ....


const StyledView1 = styled.View`
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
`;

const StyledView2 = styled.View`
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 75px;
`;

const MainContentContainer = styled.View<MainContentSectionProps>`
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: green;
  ${(props) => css`
    ${props.topLeftRadius && `border-top-left-radius: ${BORDER_RADIUS}px;`}
    ${props.topRightRadius &&
    `border-top-right-radius: ${BORDER_RADIUS}px;`}
    ${props.bottomLeftRadius &&
    `border-bottom-left-radius: ${BORDER_RADIUS}px;`}
    ${props.bottomRightRadius &&
    `border-bottom-right-radius: ${BORDER_RADIUS}px;`}
  `};
`;
```

below is the design i want to achieve with this:

[image: design]

Answer (score -1):

Use rgba color value like this.

backgroundColor: “rgba(255,255,255,0.5)”;

the last value is alpha value from 0 to 1, 0 is transparent and 1 is opaque.